# Validate Payment Response [Success / Reject] with regex

Tags: regex, laravel

I am working with peach payments service using Laravel to process new registrations and recurring transactions for users. I want to validate the response is a success or a fail based on the response code.

Based on their documentation, response 000.400.* are the only codes when a transaction is SUCCESSFUL - All others below are REJECTS.

This is the response I get when sending payment requests.

```
    {
        "id": "8ac7a49f7a5f92a7017a5fc0841160c1",
        "paymentType": "DB",
        "merchantTransactionId": "2020000116",
        "result": {
            "code": "100.150.200",
            "description": "registration does not exist"
        },
        "customer": {
            "givenName": "John",
            "surname": "Doe",
            "merchantCustomerId": "202003"
        },
        "buildNumber": "9f3644d682d5e2ddc14a54kj45j45472d@2021-06-28 11:45:06 +0000",
        "timestamp": "2021-03-01 01:48:10+0000",
        "ndc": "8ac7a4c96de4545fg45dfgdfg454dfg57_6d182b72e1aa46d2a71cda57c00e0ffc"
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation

Result codes for successfully processed transactions

> The regular expression pattern for filtering out this group is:
> /^(000.000.|000.100.1|000.[36])/

Result codes for successfully processed transactions that should be manually reviewed

> The regular expression pattern for filtering out this group is:
> /^(000.400.0[^3]|000.400.[0-1]{2}0)/

Result codes for pending transactions

> The regular expression pattern for filtering out this group is:
> /^(000.200)/. These codes mean that there is an open session in the
> background, meaning within half an hour there will be a status change,
> if nothing else happens, to timeout.

Result codes for rejections due to 3Dsecure and Intercard risk checks

> The regular expression pattern for filtering out this group is:
> /^(000.400.[1][0-9][1-9]|000.400.2)/

Result codes for rejections by the external bank or similar payment system

> The regular expression pattern for filtering out this group is:
> /^(800.[17]00|800.800.[123])/

Result codes for rejections due to communication errors

> The regular expression pattern for filtering out this group is:
> /^(900.[1234]00|000.400.030)/

```
$re = '/^(000\.400\.0[^3]|000\.400\.[0-1]{2}0)/';

$str = '000.400';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);

dd($matches);
```

Ref:https://peachpayments.docs.oppwa.com/reference/resultCodes